# Как сделать считывание и занесение в БД каждый час.java.spring booot.Scheduling Tasks

Tags: java, spring-boot

Скажите , пожалуйста, как сделать считывание каждый час ?
Моя задача по часового считывания данных с сайта openweathermap, занесения их в бд и получение по rest запросу . никак не могу сделать почасовое считывание и занесение в бд.
[проект на github](https://github.com/damchaa/datajpa)

Класс в котором сохраняю в бд .

```
public class GreetingController {
@Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
        CustomerRepository customerRepository;
private  final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();


//@RequestMapping("/greeting")
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);


@Bean
public CommandLineRunner  demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {

        // save a couple of customers  cord,weather, base,main,wind,clouds,dt,sys,idd,name,code
        String cord = openweather.gedCoord();
        String weather = openweather.gedWeather();
        String base = openweather.gedBase();
        String main = openweather.gedMain();
        String wind = openweather.gedClouds();
        String clouds = openweather.gedClouds();
        String dt = openweather.gedDt();
        String sys = openweather.gedSys();
        String time = openweather.gedTimezone();
        String idd = openweather.gedIdd();
        String name = openweather.gedName();
        String code = openweather.gedCode();


        repository.save(new Customer(cord,weather,base,main,wind,clouds,dt,sys,time,idd,name,code));
        log.info("Customers found with findAll():");
        log.info("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            log.info(customer.toString());
        }
        log.info("");


    };
}

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public @ResponseBody
Iterable<Customer> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return customerRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

и класс в котором получаю данные с сайта

```
public class openweather {



public static String gedCoord() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String coord = "";




    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        coord = rootobj.get("coord").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return coord;
}
public static String gedWeather() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String weather = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        weather = rootobj.get("weather").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return weather;
}
public static String gedBase() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String base = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        base = rootobj.get("base").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return base;
}
public static String gedMain() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String main = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        main = rootobj.get("main").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return main;
}
public static String gedWind() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String wind = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        wind = rootobj.get("wind").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return wind;
}
public static String gedClouds() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String clouds = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        clouds = rootobj.get("clouds").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return clouds;
}
public static String gedDt() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String dt = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        dt = rootobj.get("dt").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return dt;
}
public static String gedSys() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String sys = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        sys = rootobj.get("sys").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return sys;
}

public static String gedTimezone() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String time = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        time = rootobj.get("timezone").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return time;
}
public static String gedIdd() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String idd = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        idd = rootobj.get("id").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return idd;
}
public static String gedName() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String name = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        name = rootobj.get("name").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return name;
}
public static String gedCode() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String cod = "";


    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        cod = rootobj.get("cod").toString(); //just grab the zipcode

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    return cod;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать аннотацию `@Sheduled`. Эта аннотация позволяет повесить таймер на метод.

1. Повесьте аннотацию `@EnableSheduling` на класс с аннотацией `@SpringBootApplication`
2. Повесьте аннотацию `@Sheduled` на нужный метод который будет вызывать метод-парсер.
3. Сконфигурируйте таймер. Например, для вызова метода каждый час используйте `@Sheduled(fixedRate = "3600")`. Метод будет вызываться каждые 3600 секунд.

Аннотация также может принимать cron-выражение.
Пример: `@Sheduled(cron = "0 0 * ? * * *")`

Comment: спасибо большое еще надо было передать чуть чуть класс